# Not displaying react component using Express node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I am having big trouble to display my React component to a simple HTML page using an `Express` Node.js server. I am not having any code error **but the page does not display anything**, because the HTML `id="root"` is not populated with the React component that I am serving through my `index.js`.

This is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <!-- Using our react -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./src/index.js"></script>
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <!-- Importing bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>CISC Grader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <div>Hello</div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and this is my `server.js`

```
// Built-in Node.js modules
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

// Third-party Node.js modules
let express = require('express');

// Express App
let public_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// let port = 80; // production port
let port = 8000; // test/debug port

let app = express();
app.use(express.static(public_dir));

//response with index file

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Now listening on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: The html file is being delivered by the server?

Comment: yes, with the `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})` so when I go to my localhost:8000 I have a blank page which clearly did not load the React Components @RanderGabriel

Comment: You can't use JSX tags inside JS files and open directly on the browser, you have to preprocess it to convert it to a javascript file

Comment: Follow this link https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute

Comment: You're clearly using files from `create-react-app` but seem to have abandoned using it properly (i.e. `yarn build` -> deploy). So assuming you have moved the `src` folder into the `public` folder, `<script type="text/babel">` will still not do anything on its own; you need to also include babel so it processes and runs your script. Still, I'd definitely recommend using cra as intended.